# Help calculating improper integral

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

How do I calculate the integral $$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}xe^xdx$$ I've tried using integration by parts but I got stuck at calculating the limits.

Comment: Use partial integration.

Comment: @ThePirateBay I have. Partial integration and integration by parts are the same things.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your question. Anyways, what is the problem then?

Comment: This function is unbounded, and grows exponentially as $x\to\infty$. One could compute something like $$\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}dx$$as a convergent integral, but the one you have diverges.

Answer (score 2):

If the integral converges, then so does $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{x}\,dx$$ But $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{x}\,dx=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{M}xe^{x}\,dx=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}xe^{x}-e^{x}\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=M}=\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}e^{M}(M-1)+1=\infty$$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You know that
$$\int xe^xdx=xe^x-\int e^xdx=xe^x-e^x+C$$
Therefore
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^xdx=\left.\left(xe^x-e^x\right)\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\infty$$
So you can see that the integral doesn't converge.

### Edit

Here is the proof that this integral diverges.

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n}xe^xdx&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{2n}(n-1)+n+1}{e^n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{2n}(n-1)}{e^n}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{e^n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^n(n-1)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac d{dn}(n+1)}{\frac d{dn}\left(e^n\right)}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^n(n-1)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\\&=\infty+0\\&=\infty\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you show specifically why the limits approach infinity ?

Comment: @MinhDatHa. Added the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to find integrals from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is to break the infinite interval into two sections, in this case maybe $(-\infty,0),\ [0,\infty).$ But for your integrand $xe^x,$ the integral over the second interval does not connverge.